# am looking for this diy part to add with my project

Tags: components

am trying to build a custom rat trap and looking for this part in video.
Am looking for this part just don't know the name for it, please take a look at the youtube video with the time provided and Se what kind of part is that and where i can buy that from.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BqlwUXP-ubI

time 3:46 = 3:48 
that orange part that comes out

Comment: voting to close ... your question has nothing to do with electronics design and definitely not with Arduino

Comment: its part of Arduino project i need the part sir.

Comment: which part of your question is about the arduino?

Comment: in post 1 time 3:46 = 3:48 i need this part don't know the name of it.

Comment: The orange plunger that kills the rat is most likely a custom plastic piece. Hidden from view is most likely a pneumatic piston that drives the orange plunger. It is most likely controlled by a valve (probably fired by a transistor controlled by a microcontroller). This is mostly a mechanical problem, not electrical.

Comment: This is a shopping question. It could be for an Arduino, a mac, a Dell etc etc

Comment: @SolarMike The orange part (hammer) is certainly not a Dell or a Mac (both being closer in characteristics to a boat anchor) and Arduino's do not usually come in that size, shape or colour. An etc etc just may :-) || IF you are going to play the "Shopping Question" card it pays to actually look at what is being asked and described. If that's undesired (which is entirely up to you) then passing on by on the other side is recommended. I comment because adasd is going to have enough trouble with all the other nay sayers here without us adding spurious input).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon that device could be controlled by many things, microcontroller etc. It does not change the fact that it is written as a shopping question.

Comment: @SolarMike You are correct on both counts. But your comment was not. I suspect he's operating somewhat beyond the edge of his competence locus, and if we have to make his life harder (we don't) then not confusing him is arguably consistent with "be nice". | My answer (which I imagine will not be overly useful to him but which MAY help others in a general sense) deshoppifies his quest while (hopefully) giving him some other approach to think about. [I'm in NZ, fwiw. We have major rodent problems endangering our wildlife. Our only native mammal is a bat! ].

Comment: @RussellMcMahon my original comment was trying to make the point that many things could be used to control the device which is why I mention mac, Dell etc. I tend to keep my comments short and concise.

Comment: i need the part the rest i will handle the controller

Answer (score 4):

The overall product is a "[**goodnature A24 rat & stoat trap**](https://goodnature.co.nz/?gclid=CjwKCAiAgqDxBRBTEiwA59eENxsrBFzXE6zKxrbPgJJGLFTRjBJDZ_E4rFvYOSq1yEAgXJCJ8uryOBoCzTkQAvD_BwE)"  (made in New Zealand).

[image]

You COULD do this "easily enough" electromechanically - and it could be more effective. see - **"Another Solution"** below

You cannot buy just the portion that you have identified (except perhaps as a spare part at excessive cost) - and it would be of no use to you buy itself.

The trap is pneumatically powered by a gas cylinder.
To function it needs a rat attractor, passage for rat entry, rat detector, pneumatic 'hammer', plus electronics and battery. Any one part is of no great use by itself.

About the best you can gain from this is the concepts involved in making a pneumatically powered hammer triggered by a sensor and related electronics.

---

**ANOTHER SOLUTION:**

If you are interested in the pneumatic hammer, then an electromechanical version would be "easy enough" to implement, and would have some advantages.

1. A solenoid driven hammer with enough energy would be possible, but the power levels may be unattractive. Entirely "out of my head" I'd imagine that 1 kg.metre is on the light side to kill humanely with certainty and 10 kg.metre very adequate.
   10 kg.metre (drop a 10 kg weight one metre) =~ 100 Joule = 100 Watt.seconds.
   A Lithium Ion 18650 cell contains about 35,000 Watt seconds of energy -  so properly applied you could get about 100 activations at around 30% efficient use of energy per liIon cell!.
2. An approach that needs a much lower instantaneous energy load is to wind up a spring or similar with a suitably geared motor. The spring drives the hammer and is released by a trigger mechanism.

There will be numerous other possible approaches.

I personally dislike killing any 'significant'* living thing if it can be avoided.
Ants get warned off if possible :-).
Possums get relocated.
I'm aware that such approaches are not always considered practical.
* I won't even start on what that may mean :-).

Comment: my house is infested

Comment: will it be anything like micro pneumatic system 120psi or more

Comment: "Easier" might be a "self resetting" rat trap that uses a geared motor to pull back the sprung arm on a conventional trap. || There are many tutorials on web of traps that use a "see saw" type system, or a rotating cylinder, that cause rats to overbalance and fall into a bin - often water filled so that they drown. I dislike them immensely as they are very cruel to the animal, but would be easier to build than one of the sort seen in the video.

Comment: Best rat catcher I had was a farm cat - self powered, self feeding and self-replacing.